# How to convert .docx to .odt with Libreoffice on Ubuntu bash

Tags: ubuntu, docx, libreoffice, odt

There is a problem for converting DOCX to PDF using Libreoffice.(in RTL documents)
but converting same document saved in ODT format will works fine.

Anyone knows how to convert an existing DOCX file to ODT using Ubuntu bash?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Then you can use this command directly from command line

**libreoffice --headless --convert-to odt *.docx**

Comment: This also works on OSX but the full path to the binary becomes: **/Applications/LibreOffice.app/Contents/MacOS/soffice**. The ODT will be written to the shell's current working directory.

Comment: However, see this problem: https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/convert-file-from-docx-to-odt-with-libreoffice/60609 Sometimes it is better to use the libreoffice GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly save it to odt format in Libre Office.

1. Click on save as
2. Select ODT as format
3. Name the file
4. Click on ok