# Convert .odt to .docx in pandoc

Tags: docx, pandoc, odt

I am trying to convert my libre office document into an ms word document through the following command

```
pandoc CS141Exam.odt -f markdown -t docx -s -o test1.docx
```

but I'm getting the following errors

```
pandoc: Cannot decode byte '\xac': Data.Text.Encoding.Fusion.streamUtf8: Invalid UTF-8 stream
```

What is the correct command to achieve this?

Comment: `pandoc` can write to odt but not read from it. See [this list of input formats](http://pandoc.org/README.html#description). You can use the built-in converter in libreoffice : `libreoffice --convert-to docx CS141Exam.odt`

Comment: @scoa per your link, pandoc shd be able to read it: "It can read Markdown, CommonMark, PHP Markdown Extra, GitHub-Flavored Markdown, and (subsets of) Textile, reStructuredText, HTML, LaTeX, MediaWiki markup, TWiki markup, Haddock markup, OPML, Emacs Org mode, DocBook, txt2tags, EPUB, ODT and Word docx;"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've got pandoc trying to convert "from" (`-f`) markdown, "to" (`-t`) docx. But you're giving it an `odt` file. So it's trying to read that `odt` as though it were markdown and choking, because it isn't markdown. You want something closer to:

```
pandoc CS141Exam.odt -f odt -t docx -s -o test1.docx
```

*but*... odt isn't supported [until pandoc 1.15.1](http://pandoc.org/releases.html#pandoc-1.15.1-15-oct-2015), so do `pandoc -v` to make sure you've got a current version, too. My Ubuntu stable repo gave me 1.12.4.2 -- I had to get [the latest directly from pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest), but then this worked fine for me:

```
pandoc -f odt -t docx -o example.docx example.odt
```

(Though I don't have MS Word so all I know is that `example.docx` looks fine in LibreOffice Writer)

Comment: You can also install pandoc from source to get the latest version (http://pandoc.org/installing.html). I would still recommend using libreoffice or openoffice (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21845789/how-to-convert-docx-to-odt-with-libreoffice-on-ubuntu-bash) since pandoc will first translate the odt to native pandoc, then back to docx, losing some formatting in the process.